# htaccess not redirecting url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

So I've been stuck on this a bit, and its more or less put a top on my project.

Just started up at a new job, and my current assignment is to create an API system for a new project we're launching. Its based on a modified version of wordpress, and my objective here is to take any request that goes to /contrib/api and instead have it direct to a file I have setup to sort out the incoming URL and redirect accordingly.

Here's what I currently have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /contrib/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/
    RewriteRule ^/content/apis/apis\.php$ - [L]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

    # uploaded files -- no longer needed since we're serving files directly via apache
    # RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

    # add a trailing slash to /network and /wp-admin
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin/network$ $1wp-admin/network/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) wordpress/$2 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ wordpress/$2 [L]
    RewriteRule . /contrib/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This was all here before me, except for near the top:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/
RewriteRule ^/content/apis/apis\.php$ - [L]
```

My goal, as stated, is to take any request from /contrib/api/ and redirect it to my file instead of continuing. Instead, it seems to skip on and go ahead and point to the wp-admin (after a redirect I think). Regardless, it seems my command isn't getting caught, and I'm not sure why.

I thought that the commands are processed first come, but if its continuing on, would moving my code to the end make it work?

I know this is an easy thing to test, but I was hoping I could get some insight on what I'm doing/doing wrong, plus I don't yet have access to the server to actually upload/test code without going through my boss, and I'm thinking 2 weeks in, probably not a good idea to ask my boss to test code every 5 minutes, heh :(

EDIT: As per Bob Vale's notice, fixed the path issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `RewriteCond` as the rule will be doing the match anyhow, you just need

```
 RewriteRule ^contrib/api/ /content/apis/apis.php [L]
```

This will rewrite any url starting with contrib/api to the file /content/apis/apis.php

Comment: Ok, actually, it should be
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/
RewriteRule ^/contrib/apis/apis\.php$ - [L]`
I messed up the file structure.

But still, shouldn't it attempt to forward to the file but then fail because it can't find the file (in my incorrect code)?

Also, isn't the RewriteCond necessary? I only want to forward to the API if the url calls for it, everything else should move to the Wordpress as below?

Comment: @RhoVisions nope, your rule stops because the path does not match, when the conditions are not met it stops there and does nothing.

Comment: @RhoVisions the `RewriteCond` is unnecessary if the `RewriteRule` already defines the match which my updated answer does. You'd only really use a rewritecond if the target php file was also under the same Url and you needed the cond to explicitly exclude it

Comment: Ok, that makes a lot of sense, and I'll give it a shot first thing in the morning, thanks! Will your updated answer match anything that comes under contrib/api/? For example, if someone does contrib/api/auth? Or can I use a wildcard to match?

Comment: @RhoVisions that is an wildcard already. By not using the `$` at the end of it it means that `^contrib/api/` will match anything that starts with `contrib/api/` so `contrib/api/auth` or `contrib/api/auth/anything` or `contrib/api/something` are all included.

Comment: Ok, so its like a substring match rather than an exact match. Great, thanks!